# French translation for "Cookies preferences"?

Tags: terminologie

what would be the best translation for "Cookies preferences" in French?

Comment: in relation to web browsers

Comment: Please clarify even more in the context. Is it in relation with a website/GDPR?

Comment: Yes, it's in the context of web sites functionality

Comment: Choix de https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/Cookies%20preferences%0A : « Préférences pour les cookies » ou « Préférences en matière de cookies ». Ur clic droit sur *pour* ou *matière* vous offre d'autres possibilités.

Comment: Hi, it seems that your two comments, which were intended as clarifications, are contradictory. The first comment suggests that the question is about cookies preferences that you set in a browser (and which would apply to all websites), whereas the second comment suggests that it's about dialogs shown by websites. Please edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was under the impression that in both cases the term cookies has the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je viens de voir *Choix cookies* sur un site mais la formulation semble maladroite (*cookies* est utilisé ici comme un adjectif).
On pourrait traduire littéralement *Préférences de cookies* mais la formulation *Options de cookies* me parait plus claire.

Sur suggestion de SkyLand77, la traduction *Gérer les cookies* est également claire et naturelle.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a specific word in French for the term cookies in programming?

Comment: @ClaireRoss —  *cookies* = *informations* qui reste ‘chez vous’ comme des petits gâteaux que l'on offre aux visiteurs.

Comment: @ClaireRoss No we use the english word, et sacha je ne sais pas pour vous mais moi étant au canada j'ai : Réglages des cookies

Comment: Cookies are sometimes referred to as *mouchards* (snitches), but the word is rarely used, probably for being derogatory unlike "cookies".

Comment: @SkyLand77 Je suis Français, j'ai cherché sur quelques sites, notamment des médias, je n'en ai trouvé qu'un qui proposait le "Choix cookies", les autres n'utilisaient pas ce genre de formulation.
Google Chrome ne propose pas d'option similaire chez moi.

Comment: Je vois très souvent *préférences de cookie*, à tel point que je comprends intuitivement la signification, désormais.

Comment: @Sacha moi c'est souvent quand j'utilise le web sur mon téléphone (Safari), selon le site sur lequel je rentre j'ai des appellations différentes pour le "choix" cookies, ou "preferences" ...  je pense que c'était plus quelque chose comme "gérer", plutot que réglages, anyway je pense qu'elles sont toutes un peu similaire au final (les appellations)

Comment: @SkyLand77 "Gérer les cookies" oui je me souviens avoir déjà vu cette formulation. Je me permets de l'ajouter dans ma réponse.
En effet les appellations sont similaires et en absence de "norme", chaque site fait un peu ce qu'il veut pour l'instant.

Comment: L'apprentissage et l'usage d'une langue ne se fait pas uniquement en lisant un dictionnaire, mais également au travers des usages. Il n'y a rien de pathétique là dedans.
Bien qu'il existe des différences entre ces trois mots, ils peuvent être légitimement utilisés pour désigner la même chose dans ce contexte précis.

Comment: @20goto10 Oh .. on te demande pardon (: Je suis désolé de te l'apprendre mais dans ce cas de figure-ci elles le sont. Évidemment que pris a part elles n'ont absolument rien en commun.. Il faut suivre avant de venir faire la morale. Dans mon apprentissage de la langue j'ai eu a faire plus souvent recours a mes amis francophones qu'un dictionnaire (: c'est pour cela qu'on échange .. ( sans jugement )

Answer (score 1):

I would think the best French language translation would be *gestion des témoins (de connexion)* ([Franceterme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=t%C3%A9moin%20de%20connexion&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), [GDT](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2075216)), because it's [meaningful](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8T0319) and because cookies is something you want to *manage* rather than *personalize* per se (less you cook them with decorations on top), but the term *cookie(s)* is no doubt [very much in use](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=506798) at this point in time. [*Préférences, options, paramètres*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8362364) are all useful but the "préférences de cookies" is in essence a mostly complete phrase loan from English which doesn't help with making this meaningful; nevertheless it should be popular. This answer relies on material introduced first in [another answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43909/25619).

Comment: Well at least you'll learn something about the French language with this answer, which is actually the goal of the site. Parotting the English language is not. Nor is circlejerking.

Answer (score 0):

No native speaker. For cookies one uses in French the same wording as in English.
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_(informatique)#Id%C3%A9es_re%C3%A7ues.

There are two other translations: témoin ; témoin de connexion (http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/INFO52) but I have not heard being used.

I guess "préférences (des) cookies" would be ok. For instance,
https://www.edenred.fr/preference-cookies

> Gérer vos préférences cookies